# Adding Advanced Custom Fields to posts without hyperlinks

Tags: taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to display custom fields on my post like this:

```
<ul>
                    <li><?php the_field('name_of_placement'); ?></li>
                    <?php
                            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'country' );
                            $names = array();

                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                $names[] = $term->name;
                            }

                            echo '<li>' . implode( ', ', $names ) . '<li>';
                    ?>
                    <?php
                            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'timeframe' );
                            $names = array();

                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                $names[] = $term->name;
                            }

                            echo '<li>' . implode( ', ', $names ) . '<li>';
                    ?>
                    <li><?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'types_of_healthcare_placement' ); ?></li>

                </ul>
```

The problem is like this form creates an extra blank `<li>` item after each field.

```
http://electives-abroad.org/custom-field-test/
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be good to me, may be try to correct this line :

```
echo '<li>' . implode( ', ', $names ) . '<li>';
```

To :

```
echo '<li>' . implode( ', ', $names ) . '</li>';
```

You forget to close the li tag.

Same thing here :

```
echo '<li>' . implode( ', ', $names ) . '</li>';
```

Comment: Now it looks ok, instead of having a closing </li>, every sentence had another opening <li>

Why does the 'types_of_healthcare_placement' taxonomy appear blank? it should be the same as the other two.

Comment: +1. And @DrawsRenGundam, are you sure the taxonomy slug (`types_of_healthcare_placement`) is correct? And that there are actually terms in that taxonomy which are *assigned to the post*?

Comment: My bad, it was just "healthcare". Now it appears correctly:

http://electives-abroad.org/custom-field-test/

Problem solved.